# How to make sourceMap option in tsconfig.json dynamic via webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs, source-maps, tsconfig

I am using `webpack` to compile my `typescript` related `.tsx` files that also make use of `jsx` plus `ES2015/stage-0` syntax.

My `webpack.config.js` file is as follows:

```
var PATHS = {
    "build": path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    "myModule1": path.join(__dirname, 'js', 'module1'),
    "myModule2": path.join(__dirname, 'js', 'module2')
}

var scriptIncludes = [PATHS.myModule1, 
                      PATHS.myModule2]

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "my-module1": path.join(PATHS.myModule1, 'index.jsx'),
        "my-module2": path.join(PATHS.myModule2, 'index.tsx')
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
        path: PATHS.build
    },

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // resolvable extensions.
        // Files with the following extensions are fair game for webpack to process.
        extensions: ['', ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"],
        alias: {
            'ie': 'component-ie'
        }
    },
    plugins: [], //plugins,
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js*/,
            include: scriptIncludes,
            loader: "babel-loader", query: { presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'] } 
        },
        {
            // The loader that handles ts and tsx files. These are compiled
            // with the awesome-typescript-loader and the output is then passed through to the
            // babel-loader. The babel-loader uses the es2015, react and stage-0 presets
            // in order that jsx and es6 are processed.
            // Note that order of loader processing is from right to left.
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            include: scriptIncludes,
            loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-0!awesome-typescript-loader'
        }],
        preLoaders: [
          // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
};
```

My `tsconfig.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Now:

1. If I set `sourceMap` option in `tsconfig.json` true, only then source maps are generated. I want to make it dynamic based upon some command-line argument and not every time hard code it in `tsconfig.json` file.
   How can I achieve that thing?
2. Also if I comment `preLoaders` option in webpack configuration, would it make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass compiler options inside loader query string

e.g

> awesome-typescript-loader?sourceMap=false

Comment: For command line support you could do something like 


>awesome-typescript-loader?sourceMap=process.env.TS_SOURCEMAPS

and build it using

>[export|set] TS_SOURCEMAPS=true && webpack